# Using allow_writeable_chroot=YES in vsftpd.conf

Tags: apache, gnutls, vsftpd

I've had difficulty setting up vsftpd on my apache2 server. I was getting this error:

> GnuTLS error -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received.

Tried a number of things including updating gnutsl, permissions, different ftp clients, etc.

I eventually got it working by adding this to `vsftpd.conf`:

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

Not really sure what the implications of that. So my question is this: does that open any security issues I should worry about?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It allows for your dot files to be editable, which is often a control mechanism.

mainly .htaccess